# How to match text and skip HTML tags using a regular expression?

Tags: html, regex

I have a bunch of records in a [QuickBase](https://www.quickbase.com/) table that contain a rich text field. In other words, they each contain some paragraphs of text intermingled with HTML tags like `<p>`, `<strong>`, etc.

I need to migrate the records to a new table where the corresponding field is a plain text field. For this, I would like to strip out all HTML tags and leave only the text in the field values.

For example, from the below input, I would expect to extract `just a small example link to a webpage`:

```
  <p>just a small <a href="#">
  example</a> link</p><p>to a webpage</p>
```

As I am trying to get this done quickly and without coding or using an external tool, I am constrained to using [Quickbase Pipelines](https://www.pipelines.quickbase.com/)' [Text channel](https://helpv2.quickbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/4473004668436-Text-channel-) tool. The way it works is that I define a regex pattern and it outputs only the bits that match the pattern.

So far I've been able to come up with this regular expression (Python-flavored as QB's backend is written in Python) that correctly does the exact opposite of what I need. I.e. it matches only the HTML tags:

```
/(<[^>]*>)/
```

In a sense, I need the negative image of this expression but have not be able to build it myself.

Your help in "negating" the above expression is most appreciated.

Comment: I would like to give you a bit of advice. Do not, not, use regex for HTML. It's not a good idea. HTML is not a regular language, which makes it difficult to parse with regex. Use an HTML parsing library.

Comment: @shib thanks for trying to help. I am aware of the limitations of regular expression. As I've written in my question, I am constrained in the selection of technology available to me. Additionally, this is a limited use case where the input includes very simple, machine-generated HTML tags and so I am hopeful a regex can yield the best ROI.

Comment: do `<` or `>` appear anywhere where they do not denote tags? (You could check for `<[^>]*<` or `>[^<]*>`) Can they appear in attributes?

Comment: Thanks @jhnc. `<` and `>` do not appear in attributes in my specific case. They are also encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` when appearing in the text itself. I just tried both the expressions you gave but they don't match anything for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: googling quickbase pipelines, it seems to [use jinja templates](https://helpv2.quickbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/4473004144660-Transforming-your-data-) and those understand [`striptags()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#striptags), or perhaps you can even just do something like `{{a.body|text}}`

Comment: @jhnc thank you. Before trying regex, I tried `|text`, `|striptags` and `|html2text`. None of these work. :?

Comment: It's essential to know what regex flavor the tool supports. PCRE e.g. [`<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<]+`](https://regex101.com/r/Vj1Oz1/1), ... Java (support for possessive quantifier) e.g. [`[^><]++(?!>)`](https://regex101.com/r/EykwGb/1) ... using lookbehind: [`(?:(?<=>)|^)[^<]+`](https://regex101.com/r/oXgHTV/1)

Comment: Thank you @bobblebubble. I really should have mentioned it. The tool is written in Python so that's the flavor for the pattern.

Comment: The last one from the regexes that I posted before: [`(?:(?<=>)|^)[^<]+`](https://regex101.com/r/oXgHTV/1) will work in Python as long `<` and `>` do not occur elsewhere or are escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: That does look like it does the trick. Thanks so much. Would you like to promote this to answer so I can accept? What does the `|^` part mean?

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that helped :) I put an answer with a bit explanation how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no `<` or `>` elsewhere or entity-encoded, an idea using a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?:(?<=>)|^)[^<]+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oXgHTV/1)

`(?:(?<=>)|^)` is an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) between either `^` [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) of the string or looking behind for any `>`. From there `[^<]+` matches [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) characters that are not `<` ([negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)).